# Why is my return value undefined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, return

I have an array called questionSets full of objects. The createSet function should create new or create a copy of an existing questionSets object. The function getQuestionsFromSet is used if createSet is used to make a copy. For some reason when I call getQuestionsFromSet() from inside createSet() I always get a returned value of 'undefined'. I can't figure out why because when I do a console.log() of the value to be returned by getQuestionsFromSet() I see exactly what I want.

I have these two functions.

```
function createSet(name, copiedName) {
    var questions = [];
    if (copiedName) {
        questions = getQuestionsFromSet(copiedName);
    }
    console.log(questions); // undefined. WHY??
    questionSets.push({
        label: name,
        value: questions
    });
}; // end createSet()

function getQuestionsFromSet(setName) {
    $.each(questionSets, function (index, obj) {
        if (obj.label == setName) {
            console.log(obj.value); // array with some objects as values, which is what I expect.
            return obj.value;
        }
    });
}; // end getQuestionsFromSet()
```

Comment: console.log is showing values?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal There is no Ajax call there!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `getQuestionsFromSet()` does not `return` anything and so is implicitly *undefined*.

What you need is probably something like:

```
function getQuestionsFromSet(setName) {
    var matched = []; // the array to store matched questions..
    $.each(questionSets, function (index, obj) {
        if (obj.label == setName) {
            console.log(obj.value); // array with some objects as values, which is what I expect.
            matched.push(obj.value); // push the matched ones
        }
    });
    return matched; // **return** it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`return obj.value;` is nested within the inner `$.each(function{})`, and `getQuestionsFromSet` is indeed not returning anything.